# Can't ping guest machine on Hyper-V setup

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, hyper-v

I'm having a problem with a Hyper-V configuration.  I can ping the host from the guest, but not the guest from the host!

Here's my setup:

- The host has its own NIC connecting to the network.
- The guest has been assigned another NIC on the physical machine and is using a virtual adapter to connect.

Everything else is pretty standard.

Can anybody suggest any reason as to why this might be the case?

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Try disabling AV and double check your that your default gateway is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably tried these things already but its worth mentioning.

Have you updated your network card drivers, I was using intel and had to download the latest from the intel site because of a network related issue, where the guest would not always be reachable after boot.

Are you using NAT for the guest?
In which case the ping can go out and works correctly, but not the other way around.

Do you have a firewall enabled on the guest that is discarding the pings, in but allowing them out?

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar issue and found that it was resolved by opening the Virtual Network Manager for the host machine, removing the Virtual Network, applying that, and then recreating a new one (using the defaults for all properties in my case) - seemingly miraculously, connectivity was restored...